# How To Highlight Parent <Li> When Child <Li> Is Active using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar which include links and sub links.
Here is my code -

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <ul style='list-style:none;'>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li id='post_list'> <a href="#">Posts</a>
      <ul style='list-style:none;' id='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/all_posts'); ?>'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/add_post'); ?>'>Add</a></li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/post_categories'); ?>'>Category</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id='post_list'> <a href="#">Pages</a>
      <ul style='list-style:none;' id='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/all_pages'); ?>'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/add_page'); ?>'>Add</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class='media_upload'>Media</a></li>
    <li id='post_list'> <a href="#">User</a>
      <ul style='list-style:none;' id='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/all_users'); ?>'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/add_new_user'); ?>'>Add</a></li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/user_profile'); ?>'>Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/logout')?>">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My question is how to set active class to parent li when it's child li is clicked?
Thanks.

Comment: **Identifiers must be unique**. > `id='sub_links'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `id`s **must be uniqe!** And if I were you I would change `id` attribute to `class`, like so:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <ul style='list-style:none;'>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class='post_list'> 
      <a href="#">Posts</a>
      <ul style='list-style:none;' class='sub_links'>
        <li>
          <a href='<?php echo site_url(' admin/all_posts '); ?>'>All</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then in your JS file:

```
$(".sub_links li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).closest(".post_list").addClass('active');
});
```

Here you go, should work

Answer (score 1):

use this code.

```
 $('#mySidenav ul ul li').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
 });
```

**Explanation**: The selector `#mySidenav ul ul li` will make sure it selects the innermost `li` tags and on click of this `li` tag the `$(this).closest('li')` will find the parent `li` ie: the closest `li` tag from the clicked `li` tag and adds the class `active` to it using `.addClass('active')`

**side note:** Also make sure you don't have duplicate id's in the HTML. 
`id='post_list'` and `id='sub_links'` . Id's in HTML are meant to be unique, Else you might have issue while writing jquery or css using this id in the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, convert your id `sub_links` to class.

You can use jQuery's `parents()` method for your problem

```
$('#mySidenav li').on('click', function(e) {
  if($(this).parents('li').length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }
  else{
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swfkune4/)

Comment: @
Sebastian Your code is working but when page does not loads. I want to set active link when page loads.

Comment: Just set your first element's class ( **Dashboard** in your case?)as `active`

The rest you'll be able to change using jQuery anyway.

Comment: I have set first element's class active but still that is not working on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sub_links have a li class active do this at page ready:

```
$('li.active').parent().closest('li').addClass('active');
```

```js
 $('li.active').parent().closest('li').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active > a {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <ul style='list-style:none;'>
    <li>
      <a href="">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li id='post_list'> 
      <a href="#">Posts</a>
      <ul style='list-style:none;' id='sub_links'>
        <li>
          <a href=''>All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=''>Add</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Category</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id='post_list'>
      <a href="#">Pages</a>
      <ul style='list-style:none;' id='sub_links'>
        <li>
          <a href=''>All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=''>Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class='media_upload'>Media</a>
    </li>
    <li id='post_list'> 
      <a href="#">User</a>
      <ul style='list-style:none;' id='sub_links'>
        <li class="active">
          <a href=''>All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=''>Add</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=''>Profile</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Setting</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```